# Is Zuul an appropriate proxy for web applications?

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I'm currently using Eureka/Zuul as an api gateway for a suite of REST services. This has been successful and very convenient so far. I have api.mycompany.com and a group of contexts under that. Each one routes through Zuul to its related web service, this works great.

I also have a couple of web applications written as Spring-Boot apps. They are also registering with Eureka, in order to be found and tracked by Spring-Boot-Admin. so I was wondering if it is reasonable to also use Zuul as a proxy to web applications.

So, something like: gateway.mycompany.com/app1 points to wherever app1 is running as seen in the Eureka registry. This url would be the actual URL used in the browser to access the web application.

It seems like it should work, but I don't see any examples of doing this. So I thought I'd ask.

I tried a quick setup to see if it works, and it does appear to route correctly. The one issue I notice is that the URL in the browser is switching from the Zuul gateway url to the host/port of the Spring-Boot app. I assume there's a Zuul config option to stop that from happening, though I'm not sure how.

Comment: Note that Zuul1 is blocking and as such it doesn't support modern web technologies such as WebSockets. So whilst you certainly can use Zuul as a proxy for your web applications, you may regret it. As to your URL problem - this many not be easily fixable, or it may be as trivial as setting `server.use-forward-headers=true` in your Spring Boot application.

Comment: Thanks! I found some documentation [here (section 8.14)](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html) about rewriting location header. It is kind of working, but not exactly. But it does seem to be going in the right direction.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that - setting the correct option on the proxied server will allow it to determine what it's external URL is. Rewriting the location header is a dirty cludge, and will just cause you pain.